PEST PHP AfterAll hook not executing
I'm trying to clean up some database records using the afterAll hook, but I'm unable to.
it('can signup', function()
{
    $response = $this->post(route('signup'), [.....]);
    
    expect($response->status())->toBe(200);
});

it('can signup as existing user', function()
{
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post(route('signup'), [.....]);
    
    expect($response->status())->toBe(200);
});

afterAll(function()
{
    \App\Models\PlansSignups::where('user_id', 1)->delete(); // <--- this is never executed
});

The documentation says:

Executes the provided closure once after all tests have completed
within the current file, allowing you to perform any necessary
clean-up or tear-down tasks.

https://pestphp.com/docs/hooks#content-afterall
So why isn't the query being executed?
I know that afterAll function is called because if I can see it through XDebug, but the model / query is never executed. I've also tried with a manual statement, such as:
\DB::statement('DELETE FROM plans_signups WHERE user_id = 1');

But no luck either.
If I execute the same query within the test can signup as existing user it works, example:
it('can signup as existing user', function()
{
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post(route('signup'), [.....]);
    
    expect($response->status())->toBe(200);
    
    \App\Models\PlansSignups::where('user_id', 1)->delete(); // <--- Works great!
});


The answer lies in the PEST code... Have you checked their bugtracker? Generally, a [mcve] would be helpful.

@UlrichEckhardt you mean this https://github.com/pestphp/pest/issues/388 ?
